# Arduino _command_line_ sketch upload: avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

Tags: arduino, avrdude

When trying to upload the sketch from the command line I get a

```
avrdude -vvv -F -V -c arduino -p ATMEGA328P -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200 -U flash:w:test.hex 

avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Oct 21 2013 at 15:55:32
    Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
    Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

    System wide configuration file is "/etc/avrdude.conf"
    User configuration file is "/home/toni/.avrduderc"
    User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

    Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM0
    Using Programmer              : arduino
    Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

but **from the Arduino IDE it works flawlessly**, so, obviously, the IDE is doing something I don't know about.

I've tried activating "Show detailed output during upload" but the output window history is way too short to view the commands launched. I can only see the end of the successful upload.

I'm guessing the IDE resets somehow the Arduino to talk to the booloader before the already loaded sketch starts running

Ho could I do this from the command line (**without the IDE**) ?

Comment: what programmer setting are you having in the IDE?

Comment: I'm guessing I'm using the wrong mcu. I was using ATMEGA328P and I'm currently using a atmega2560.

Comment: Alright, so it works now? If so, please post an answer to your own question.